# Dynamic update of plugins in Jenkins

Tags: java, plugins, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Recently I used Jenkins and found that the plugins are dynamic. In the sense, we don't need to restart the Jenkins server. So I had a doubt, how does the plugins which are currently being used get updated dynamically? Will the processes using that plugin get stopped for some moment while the plugin gets updated (or) will the plugin get updated later when no processes are using them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins can be INSTALLED dynamically (no process is currently using them), but they cannot be UPDATED dynamically (because memory and processes are probably actively using them). Updated plugins are downloaded, but won't be installed until the next Jenkins restart.